# Ansible roles requiring other ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I have the following directory structure in my playbook:

```
deploy-thing
├── README.md
├── files
│   ├── thing.service
│   └── ld.local.conf
├── main.yml
├── roles
│   ├── ansible-role-add-swap
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── defaults
│   │   │   └── main.yml
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── ansible-role-build-pkgs
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   ├── ansible-role-deploy-other-thing
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── main.yml
│   │   ├── roles
│   │   │   ├── ansible-role-build-pkgs
│   │   │   │   └── tasks
│   │   │   │       └── main.yml
│   │   │   └── ansible-role-build-redis
│   │   │       ├── README.md
│   │   │       └── tasks
│   │   │           └── main.yml
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   └── main.yml
└── vars.yml
```

Within main.yml, the following is called:

```
  roles:
    - {role: ./roles/ansible-role-deploy-other-thing}
```

Within roles/ansible-role-deploy-other-thing/tasks/main.yml, the following is called:

```
  - include_role:
      name: ansible-role-build-redis
```

When run, this `include_role` causes the following error:

> ERROR! the role 'ansible-role-build-redis' was not found in
>   /Users/myuser/playbooks/deploy-thing/roles:/Users/myuser/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/Users/myuser/playbooks/deploy-thing

It appears that the parent is only searching its own roles path when running, not the role path of the role we're using (ansible-role-deploy-other-thing). How can I cause it to search its own roles path, allowing me to deploy roles within roles?

Answer (score 3):

i don't think it's a good practice to include Ansible roles on another roles. if you want any role depends on other, use the meta/main.yml file under your role to create dependency between two or more roles.

So you puts all the roles at the same level (deploy-thing/roles)

and you add meta like this on the **ansible-role-deploy-other-thing/meta/main.yml** file. (it's a best practice to create a role using ansible-galaxy  `ansible-galaxy init ansible-role-deploy-other-thing`)

```
  dependencies:
    - role: ansible-role-build-pkgs
    - role: ansible-role-build-redis
```

Read the Meta Ansible Documentation for roles dependency:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How can I cause it to search its own roles path, allowing me to deploy roles within roles?"*

A: Put the path to the roles into the configuration. See [DEFAULT_ROLES_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-roles-path). The default is

```
~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles
```

As you can see from the error message Ansible searches for roles in the configured paths plus the current directory of the playbook

```
/Users/myuser/playbooks/deploy-thing/roles:
/Users/myuser/.ansible/roles:
/usr/share/ansible/roles:
/etc/ansible/roles:
/Users/myuser/playbooks/deploy-thing
```

You'll have to add each path of the nested roles into the configuration. This makes the idea of nested roles not very practical. [Best practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) is to keep the roles flat. See more details in [Search paths in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible).